# Android: constraintLayout not working inside CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying a layout which has following general layout hierarchy
ConstraintLayout>CardView>ConstraintLayout>Button.

The 2nd constraintLayout must stick to Bottom Right of cardView.

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result]

But the constraints inside Card View are not working.

I have first tried replacing 2nd ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout but it didn't helped too. The constraints are having no effect on them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".home_fragment"
android:id="@+id/home_fragment">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/first_card"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Button 1 "
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/second_card"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/first_card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Button 2 "
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But here the 2nd ConstraintLayout is sticked to Top-Left of CardView.
I want it to be sticked at Bottom-Right of CardView.
The actual result:

[image]

Comment: Use  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  with your button and it will be done

Comment: Thats not how constraint layout works

Comment: Constraint layout is for removing multiple parent layout,   You should only use 1 constraint layout in 1 Layout  , as long as you are not forced to add it (ex scroll view will need a child) . remove the constraint layout inside the card view and keep buttons inside the main constraint directly and give them constrains to card view

Comment: @DeepPatel that didn't helped. Changing height and width to "match_parent" worked.

Comment: @Redman Sir Placing Button directly in CardView is not accepting constraint too. At very first I did the same. But didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your inner ConstraintLayout like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1 "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But why didn't the wrap_content work? Because I am placing the whole 2nd ConstraiintLayout at bottom-right of CardView and then placing button inside the 2nd ConstraintLayout.

Comment: The constraints you set for ConstraintLayout wouldn't work because it's parent layout is CardView, not ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".home_fragment"
android:id="@+id/home_fragment">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/first_card"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Button 1 "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/second_card"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/first_card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Button 2 "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But why didn't the wrap_content work? Because I am placing the whole 2nd ConstraiintLayout at bottom-right of CardView and then placing button inside the 2nd ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply constraint to your cardview child, apply `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"` to your `ConstraintLayout` inside `CardView`

Comment: Is there any kind of explanation for it?

Comment: you can even remove your constraint layout you have used inside cardview and directly use button and set its gravity. constraints thing work only with constraint layout and not with cardview.

Comment: Okay sir I got it now. That means constraints work when implemented on direct child of constraintLayout view. Right?

Answer (score 1):

you have to make your inside layout `match_parent` like below and then you can implement your `constraints` easily.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home_fragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first_card"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Button 1 "
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/second_card"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_color"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/first_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Button 2 "
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But why didn't the wrap_content work? Because I am placing the whole 2nd ConstraiintLayout at bottom-right of CardView and then placing button inside the 2nd ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @user8810517 it didn't  worked because you were not placing constraints properly. It can be done that way too like the accepted answer posted it.

Comment: Sir my constraints worked when I just changed "wrap_content" to "match_parent". There was no problem with my constraints.

Comment: @user8810517 ah yes sorry. The problem was that when you do wrap_content the content is by default starts from starting of parent not the ending.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint layout inside of cardview should have width and height match_parent. Otherwise constraint layout will shrink to match its child width and height.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    tools:context = ".home_fragment"
    android:id = "@+id/home_fragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id = "@+id/first_card"
    android:layout_width = "200dp"
    android:layout_height = "100dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor = "@color/card_color"
    app:cardCornerRadius = "15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
    android:layout_marginTop = "200dp"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent" // change this line
        android:layout_height = "match_parent" // change this line
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"

            android:text = "Button 1 "
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom = "8dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id = "@+id/second_card"
    android:layout_width = "200dp"
    android:layout_height = "100dp"

    android:layout_marginTop = "56dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor = "@color/card_color"
    app:cardCornerRadius = "20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "@id/first_card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf = "@id/first_card">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent" // change this line
        android:layout_height = "match_parent" // change this line
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
            android:text = "Button 2 "
            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: But why didn't the wrap_content work? Because I am placing the whole 2nd ConstraiintLayout at bottom-right of CardView and then placing button inside the 2nd ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Its because, 2nd constraint layout is not child of another constraint layout but of card view, so there will be no effect of this code app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent".

Constraint can be applied if it is child of constraint layout not of cardview. So it was not working

Answer (score 1):

Well to Achieve your expected result, you don't need to use constraint layout inside the CardView:

You can do that without using constraint inside CardView as below.

Just apply the `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"` to your buttons inside the CardView

Check Updated Code below and screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first_card"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Button 1 " />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/second_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/first_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Button 2 "
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Button 2 "
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It was a really good solution. But I need to add more contents inside the 2nd constraintLayout so couldn't accept the solution. But I upvoted it for the simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code and it looks perfect on my device, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

> Check this

Output :[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home_fragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first_card"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Button 1 "  
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/second_card"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/first_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_card">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Button 2 "
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But why didn't the wrap_content work? Because I am placing the whole 2nd ConstraiintLayout at bottom-right of CardView and then placing button inside the 2nd ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @user8810517 If constraintView it self wrap_content then it 's size is same as his child inside constraintView. so wrap_content not work on that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to set button on constraint button right :

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/first_card"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#3F51B5"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    >


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button_1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1 "
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button_1"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**ScreenShot:**
[image]

Comment: But why didn't the wrap_content work? Because I am placing the whole 2nd ConstraiintLayout at bottom-right of CardView and then placing button inside the 2nd ConstraintLayout.

Comment: wrap_content means The component just want to display big enough to enclose its content only. and match_parent means create view parent size.

Comment: if in constraint layout you have use wrap_content it 's size is same as his child inside constraintView. so wrap_content not work on that case

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2 "
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```